# How do you emit multiple flow values as an object at the repository level?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Say I have two flows:

```
val x: Flow<Long?> = dao.getValueX()
val y: Flow<Long?> = dao.getValueY()
```

Can I have a third flow, flow `z` which will emit these two as a pair?

Say I have `XYObject()` where XYObject looks like

```
X: Long?
Y: Long?
```

I want to basically emit a flow of `z` where it emits `XYObject` with X and Y populated from the two flows above. I actually have 3-4 things I want to emit, but kept it to two for the sake of the example.

Comment: in coureutine right? not rx?

Comment: Yes this is in a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combine()` transform function:

> Returns a Flow whose values are generated with transform function by
> combining the most recently emitted values by each flow.

[source](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html)

And define `z` like this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine

data class XYObject(val x: Long?, val y: Long?)

val x: Flow<Long?> = dao.getValueX()
val y: Flow<Long?> = dao.getValueY()
val z: Flow<XYObject> = x.combine(y) { _x: Long?, _y: Long? ->
    XYObject(_x, _y)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir. I was running two collects in the same suspend fun and things were going very much south.